# Sum Rows in Excel per Lookup Value

Tags: excel, sum, rows, lookup

I have data in Excel in the 'Applications' sheet in the following format:

```
APPLICATION_NUMBER      CUSTOMER_NUMBER       VALUE_1       VALUE_2       VALUE_3
1234                    1                     100.00         20.00         80.00
1234                    2                     100.00         20.00         80.00
9876                    1                      50.00         10.00         40.00
9876                    3                      50.00         10.00         40.00
```

I then have data in the 'Customers' sheet in the following format:

```
CUSTOMER_NUMBER    SUM_VALUE_1    SUM_VALUE_2    SUM_VALUE_3
1
2
3
```

I need to populate the summed amount of VALUE_1 to 'SUM_VALUE_1' for each customer in the 'Customers' sheet.

There are thousands of rows so need to use a formula but don't want to use a pivot table. As you can see CUSTOMER_NUMBER 1 is listed against 2 applications so I want to sum up 100.00 and 50.00 for VALUE_1 etc.

I think I need to use a SUMIF and LOOKUP but can't work it out.

Comment: you will want to sum three SUMIFs

Comment: Hi, can you help with writing one of the SUMIFs and i'll work out the other 2. Forgot to mention i need to do this summing up in a different worksheet. The example data above is in 'Applications' sheet and then the summing up will be done in 'Customers' sheet, where there will be 1 row per customer.

Comment: `=SUMIFS(Applications!$C:$C,Applications!$B:$B,1)`

Comment: Apologies, I didn't explain this fully. Have edited my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to return the sum Column:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Applications!$C:$E,0,MATCH(MID(I$1,5,999),Applications!$C$1:$E$1,0)),Applications!$B:$B,$H2)
```

You will need to change the references to match your setup.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, think i'm nearly there but i'm getting #N/A. I think it's because my VALUE_1 figures in the 'Applications' sheet are created from a vlookup to a different, third sheet. Can you think of a way around that?

Comment: If you are getting #N/A it has to do with the MID.  I based it on what you showed.  I removed the `SUM_` from the title row on the output to match the title row on the input.  Basically you are not finding a match in the title rows that way.  You will need to adjust the formula so it finds the match in the title rows.

Comment: Just found it, it was because I had the underscores missing from the title rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help Scott, have just tested it and it works a treat.